# Why list(set(a+b)) returns ordered list? And is it always returns an ordered list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I have two lists with integers. And I combine the elements of the lists to create new list without duplication. I want new list to be sorted. But when I try combine using set it returns an ordered list. I want to know why is it returning an ordered list? And is it always True?

I have tried with different values of list it returned the ordered list

```
a = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,14,15,16]
b = [1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
c = list(set(a+b))
print(c)
```

Result is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

Comment: A set can keep its elements in any order it likes, including this one. If you try with a bigger range of numbers, you'll find a case where the result does not come out in that order.

Comment: Try `a=[8]` and `b=[1]`. You will find that `list(set(a+b))=[8,1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since sets are unordered, it's not possible that the list you get after casting a set to list will be ordered.

From the docs:https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

> A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements.

Here is a very simple example where the `order` fails

```
a = [1,5]
b = [1,10,20]
c = list(set(a+b))
print(c)
#[1, 10, 20, 5]
```

To sort the combined list, just use [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)

```
In [2]: a = [1,5]                                                                                                                             

In [3]: b = [1,10,20]                                                                                                                         

In [5]: c = list(set(a+b))                                                                                                                    

In [6]: sorted(c)                                                                                                                             
Out[6]: [1, 5, 10, 20]
```

Comment: Sorry i am new to Stackoverflow so i am learning how to use it!

Comment: No worries :) Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Sets in Python are not ordered:

> Python also includes a data type for sets. A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements. Basic uses include membership testing and eliminating duplicate entries. Set objects also support mathematical operations like union, intersection, difference, and symmetric difference.

[(source)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Here is the example:

```
a = list(reversed([1,1,2,3,5,4498576,8,13,14,15,16]))
b = [1,345,132,36465,7,8,9,10,11,12]
c = list(set(a+b))
print(c)
```

prints:

`[1, 2, 3, 132, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 4498576, 36465, 345]`

If you want your list to be sorted, you should do it manually:

```
c.sort()
print(c)
```

`[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 132, 345, 36465, 4498576]`